# Powershell Show UI setting variables

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Hi I am trying to make a small GUI menu for the most common programs I run. I have a Batch Menu made up but I wanted to make a PowerShell GUI version using ShowUI Module ([Show UI Homepage](http://showui.codeplex.com/))

The Menu is working well it loads all the programs as the elevated user as expected, what isn't working is I have a second part to my Batch menu which lets me set a PC name Variable which allows me to run remote programs. (I.E. Ping/test-connection, tasklist/get-process, interactive cmd.exe)

This is proving to be difficult, there isn't much documentation on the Show UI site.  I have set it on a click of a GUI button it pops up a window to populate a variable but it never changes the variable. (when I run it that command manually it does work)

Here is my script so far: (edited out some of the programs as I might get in trouble showing them)

```
Import-Module ShowUI
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$pcname = "127.0.0.1"
$getEventInput = UniformGrid -ControlName 'Nats Menu' -Columns 2 -Rows 15 {


       New-Label -VisualStyle 'MediumText' "Nattys Menu"
       new-label " "
            New-Button "SCCM Console" -On_Click { invoke-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.exe" }
            New-Button "SCCM CCC" -On_Click { invoke-Item "C:\Program Files\Client Center for Configuration Manager\SCCMCliCtrWPF.exe" }
            New-Button "Removed Program"
            New-Button "GPeditor" -On_Click { invoke-Item "gpmc.msc" }
            New-Button "Active Directory" -On_Click { invoke-Item "dsa.msc" }
            New-Button "Powershell ISE x86" -On_Click { invoke-Item "C:\WINDOWS\sysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe" }
            New-Button "Powershell" -On_Click { invoke-Item "C:\WINDOWS\sysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" }
            New-Button "Command Prompt" -On_Click { invoke-Item "cmd.exe" } 
        new-label " "
        new-label " "
            New-Button "Set New PCName" -On_Click {$pcname = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter a computer name", "Computer") }
            New-Button -VisualStyle 'MediumText' "Show PC Name" -On_Click {$wshell.Popup("$PCName")}
            New-Button "Ping PC" -On_Click {Test-Connection $PCName -Count 5 |Out-GridView}


} -show
```

Don't know if its needed but here is the Batch Menu I made:

```
ECHO OFF
set pcname=127.0.0.1
set sysint=c:\TEMP\Sysinternals
set menutemp=c:\temp

pause 
:START
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
ECHO º                             ***Nats Menu***                                 º
ECHO ÌÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¹
ECHO º (1) Start SCCM Console                        (X) Run Startup Apps          º
ECHO º (2) Start SCCM CCC                                                          º
ECHO º (3) Start SCCM DMT                                                          º
ECHO º (4) Start GPeditor                                                          º
ECHO º (5) Start Active Directory                    (DSM) Open DSM Sessions       º
ECHO º (6) Start Powershell ISE x86                  (G) PS Get-Proc on Remote PC  º
ECHO º (7) Start Powershell                         (T) Task List on Remote PC    º
ECHO º (8) Start Command Prompt                      (P) PS Test-Conn remote PC    º
ECHO º                                               (O) PING Remote PC            º
ECHO º                                               (I) Open CMD on Remote PC     º
ECHO º                                               (C) Open C$ on Remote PC      º
ECHO º                                               (R) SCCM RC to Remote PC      º
ECHO º                                               (D) RDP to Remote PC          º
ECHO º                                               (A) Set Remote PC Name        º
ECHO ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
ECHO          Running as: %username%                    Remote PC: %PCNAME%
echo.
echo.

SET /P M=Make Selection then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO SCCMCON
IF %M%==2 GOTO SCCMCCC
IF %M%==3 GOTO SCCMDMT
IF %M%==4 GOTO GPO
IF %M%==5 GOTO AD
IF %M%==6 GOTO ISE
IF %M%==7 GOTO PS
IF %M%==8 GOTO CMD
IF %M%==p GOTO PINGPS
IF %M%==o GOTO PING
IF %M%==c GOTO CDRIVE 
IF %M%==r GOTO RCPC
IF %M%==a GOTO SETPC
IF %M%==t GOTO tasklist
IF %M%==g GOTO tasklistps
IF %M%==x GOTO startup
IF %M%==d GOTO RDP
IF %M%==i GOTO ICMD
IF %M%==dsm goto DSM

goto START

:SCCMCON
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.exe"
goto START

:SCCMCCC
start "" "C:\Program Files\Client Center for Configuration Manager\SCCMCliCtrWPF.exe"
GOTO START

:SCCMDMT
REM start "" "Removed For reasons"
GOTO START

:GPO
start "" "%SystemRoot%\system32\gpmc.msc"
GOTO START

:AD
start "" "%SystemRoot%\system32\dsa.msc"
GOTO START

:SETPC
SET /P PCNAME=Choose PC Name then Press ENTER:
goto START

:RCPC
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\i386\CmRcViewer.exe" %PCNAME%
goto START

:RDP
start "" mstsc /v:%pcname% /f
goto START

:CDRIVE
START "" \\%PCNAME%\c$
GOTO START

:PING
START "Running as %username%" %windir%\system32\ping.exe %PCNAME% -t
GOTO START

:PINGPS
START "" powershell "Test-Connection %pcname% -count 15| out-gridview | pause"
GOTO START

:TASKLIST
%sysint%\psexec.exe \\%pcname% c:\windows\system32\tasklist.exe >%menutemp%\tasklist.txt
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %menutemp%\tasklist.txt
GOTO Start

:TASKLISTPS
start "" powershell "get-process -ComputerName %PCNAME% | out-gridview | pause"
GOTO Start

:startup
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.exe"
start "" "C:\Program Files\Client Center for Configuration Manager\SCCMCliCtrWPF.exe"
start "" "%SystemRoot%\system32\gpmc.msc" /min
start "" "%SystemRoot%\system32\dsa.msc"
goto start

:ise
start "" %windir%\sysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe
goto start

:CMD
start "Running as %username%" cmd.exe
goto start

:PS
start "" powershell.exe
goto start

:ICMD
start "" %sysint%\psexec.exe \\%pcname% cmd.exe
goto start

:DSM
rem Removed for Reasons
goto start
```

As you can see making it a PowerShell script using the ShowUI module makes the script a lot easier to manage but if I cant get this variable problem solved I may have to keep using batch menu for the remote work only, and use PowerShell to launch the applications.

So if anyone has used ShowUI module before and have an idea on how to resolve this that would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Nat

Comment: does it show the correct pc name when you click "Show pc name" button?

Comment: No only shows the local host I push in at the start.  It just does not update while its running.

Comment: `$script:pcname = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter a computer name", "Computer")`

Comment: That did it thanks Mathias

Answer (score 0):

> $script:pcname = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter
>   a computer name", "Computer")

– Mathias R. Jessen Feb 29 at 7:05